# gcc, what is the purpose of asm volatile ("" : : "r" (x))

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, volatile

I have seen such of following code in a C source code, complied by gcc on Linux (for computer):

```
extern double prices[4000];

void somefunction()
{
  //this function is called again after each 5 seconds interval

  //some long codes that use prices[]
  // ...

  int i;
  for (i=0; i<4000; i++)
  {
      asm volatile ("" : : "r" (prices[i]));
  }
}
```

So I have some questions:

1. what is the purpose of the inline assembly here ?
2. look like prices[i] is the value, should it be the pointer ?
3. In my opinion, the asm code just put the prices[i] into registers for later reference, however, the number of loops is 4000, which does not make sense (computer does not have such many registers)

Comment: `volatile` means that outside influences may change the data:  don't expect it to remain stable by reloading the data every time an access is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discuss with the one who wrote the code, he said he was trying to fetch variables into CPU caches (L1/L2/L3)

Comment: I believe that's what I speculated before.  And yes, this will read things into cache.  Whether this provides any actual benefit over just letting the cpu manage this on its own is debatable.  It's more likely to do exactly what it did: Cause maintenance problems for people who work on the code later, as well as portability issues.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd how about using gcc prefetch builtin instead of this method? which one do you refer ?

Comment: The OS will automatically load memory into the cpu's cache every time you access it (such as when you load the values into the prices array).  It will also automatically toss things OUT of the cache whenever it chooses.  There is no way to "keep" things there.  Also remember that the cpu's cache is shared among all running processes.  So while you may think that moving these prices into the cache is a wonderful idea, the OS can decide that certain device driver info is more useful and toss all your stuff right back out.  So my preference is (almost always) to let the cpu/OS handle this.

Comment: One last thought: It can make sense to do this type of optimization in certain very performance-intensive routines.  If you want to find out if this is really making a difference in this case, use a profiler and time it.  You can even compare it to using prefetch.  I would be more than a little surprised to learn that any human perceptible time is being saved here.  And not surprised at all to find that it's making things slower.

Answer (score 2):

The volatile keyword tells the compiler that it's not allowed to move this assembly block.

`asm ("" ::: "memory")` is a simple compiler fence.

From [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Extended-Asm.html):

> You can prevent an asm instruction from being deleted by writing the
>   keyword volatile after the asm. [...] The volatile keyword indicates
>   that the instruction has important side-effects. GCC will not delete a
>   volatile asm if it is reachable.

Answer (score 0):

`asm volatile` forces the compile to load `prices[i]` in some register (that would be the same single register for every loop execution, you still would use one register for a loop executed 4000 times).

If you just coded `asm` without `volatile` the compiler could optimize by removing (or moving) the entire statement, then removing the entire loop since it does nothing.

Try to compile your `foo.c` code with

```
 gcc -O0 -fverbose-asm -S foo.c -o foo-O0.s
 gcc -O1 -fverbose-asm -S foo.c -o foo-O1.s
 gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S foo.c -o foo-O2.s
 gcc -O3 -fverbose-asm -S foo.c -o foo-O3.s
```

and look into the generated  `foo-O*.s` files (e.g. with an editor or a pager like `less`) with and without using the `volatile` keyword

Comment: Actually, since there are no output params, volatile is implicit.

Comment: David Wohlferd is correct.
Actually the volatile keyword is not in the question.
I just want to know what the code does: asm volatile ("" : : "r" (prices[i]));

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch seemed to answer one of my questions, however, as i stated, the number of registers in the CPU is limited, so the code would look useless because of the 4000 loops, is it correct? or does it have some other purposes ?

Comment: Other that that nit, what @basile said was correct.  Unless there is more to this code (something inside the quotes?), it is a useless time-wasting loop.

Comment: If this were a job interview question, I might diplomatically speculate that it was attempting to heat up a cache.  THEN I would say it was a useless time-wasting loop.

Comment: I have just updated the above code to specify the use of prices[]

Comment: @khanhnd: you have a misunderstanding about computer architecture and registers. You don't need 4000 registers to run your loop 4000 times, you need only one register to run your loop any arbitrary number *N* times.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch so what is the purpose of using just only one register to run a loop for 4000 times (each time with different variable) ?

Comment: Look at the generated assembly code, as I am explaining in my answer.

Comment: Ah, so after discussing with the one who wrote the code, he was trying to fetch variables into caches L1/L2/L3